# How can I fix this FPS drop following the 15/3/2017 CS:GO patch?

Tags: pc, counter-strike-global-offensive, framerate

I've been running *Counter Strike: Global Offensive* on my laptop (NVIDIA GeForce 840M 2GB and an Intel processor) at 150fps, however after the 15/3/2017 update I'm suddenly experiencing only 30fps. Worse, whenever I see an enemy and shoot it drops to 15fps.

I haven't made any changes to my PC prior to the CS:GO update on 15/3/17 which is why I think it's the culprit. I've tried reinstalling everything: Steam, CS:GO, Nvidia drivers and changed a lot of settings. I also made sure to pick the Nvidia card for the game.

Sometimes my FPS goes back to 150 but whenever I open a menu it drops back to 30 or it goes back down to 30 in a couple of minutes. Is there any way to fix this? It's making MM unplayable!

Comment: Make sure you're not using the integrated graphics of your CPU.

Comment: I did make sure I got it set on my settings

Comment: Actually that may be the case i measured my gpu usage and it says none. Going to try fixing this.

Comment: Check in your nvidia control panel settings.  Make the csgo .exe use the nvidia GPU or make it the default for all applications

Comment: Already did that but it doesn' work.

Comment: Open task manager then boot up CSGO, play some deathmatch for about a minute then go back onto your task manager and check the 'performance' tab (or whatever tab shows the usage of your components on a graph). Just as a check on your other laptop components. Could be a CPU/RAM problem.

Comment: ensure the "power management mode" int he nvidia Control panel is set to "prefer maximum performance"

Comment: Are you sure this isn't heat dissipation issues? You say it occasionally runs at 150 but jumps back down to 30 after a few minutes... sounds like your laptop is heating up and thus is slowing down your graphics card/CPU in order to generate less heat. Consider a laptop cooling pad if you haven't got one already?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this issue aswell, this only happend on both my laptops, not at all on my PC. My temporary fix is: Keep the game running offline versus bots for about half an hour. My FPS went up to about 100 meraculasly. Just make sure you don't close your game in the meantime. This is how I play for the time being, untill this issue is fixed by Valve.

Answer (score -4):

The 840m Graphics Card is pretty bad, what is the Intel Processor specs?

You may have to look into upgrading your PC.

Comment: OP has stated that the game ran fine on his PC before the game was patched...